# Break a tie in a sum of a series of points

Tags: sorting

I'm an engineer and a programmer, NOT a mathematician.  I hope that I am able to describe my problem well enough for you to understand, even though I'm incapable of asking it in "mathematician speak".

I'm trying to find a way to programmatically break ties in points earned from finishing position in a series of races.  Points are earned for each race based on finishing position.  Those points are totaled up for the series of races, and the total points are ranked to determine finishing position for the series.

The problem arises when there is a tie in the total points earned.  I need to break the tie based on "most first place finishes, then second place finishes, then third place finishes, etc".  Here is a very simple example:

```
       ||     Racer A    ||     Racer B    |
| Race || Place | Points || Place | Points |
|======||=======|========||=======|========|
|   1  ||   1   |   25   ||   2   |   22   |
|------||-------|--------||-------|--------|
|   2  ||   2   |   22   ||   1   |   25   |
|------||-------|--------||-------|--------|
|   3  ||   3   |   20   ||   4   |   18   |
|------||-------|--------||-------|--------|
|   4  ||       |        ||  18   |    2   |
|======||=======|========||=======|========|
|  TOT ||       |   67   ||       |   67   |
|======||=======|========||=======|========|
```

As you can see, the points earned results in a tie.  Racer A however needs to win the tie breaker.  Both racers have one first place finish and one second place finish, but the tie is broken when Racer A has a third place finish and Racer B does not.

As a programmer I am capable of programming a "brute force" solution as simple as I have just described, but the solution will be slow.  I am trying to find a solution that involves an additional calculation on the place or points where the result could be summed (or otherwise aggregated) to break the tie.

For example, if we let Points Earned be "p", then you could use 2^p as a tiebreaker column, and summing that up will break the tie (*in this particular case anyway*).  Example:

```
       ||     Racer A                 ||     Racer B                 |
| Race || Place | Points | TieBreaker || Place | Points | TieBreaker |
|======||=======|========|============||=======|========|============|
|   1  ||   1   |   25   |  33554432  ||   2   |   22   |   4194304  |
|------||-------|--------|------------||-------|--------|------------|
|   2  ||   2   |   22   |   4194304  ||   1   |   25   |  33554432  |
|------||-------|--------|------------||-------|--------|------------|
|   3  ||   3   |   20   |   1048576  ||   4   |   18   |    262144  |
|------||-------|--------|------------||-------|--------|------------|
|   4  ||       |        |            ||  18   |    2   |         4  |
|======||=======|========|============||=======|========|============|
|  TOT ||       |   67   |  38797312  ||       |   67   |  38010884  |
|======||=======|========|============||=======|========|============|
```

This is super convenient from a programming standpoint, because the tie breaker can always be easily calculated, the total can be easily calculated, and those results can easily be sorted (as in, a query against a database).

But there are two problems with this.  First, it doesn't work in all cases (it works in a lot of them, but not all).  Second, if the point values given are in the thousands, then the tiebreaker number will be so huge, that it is difficult to represent in a programming language or database.

Surely there is a way to break this tie that works in all cases, and doesn't use numbers so large that they are difficult for a computer to represent.  I'm all ears!

PS  I don't even know what tags to use on this question.  If you would like to add any appropriate tags, I would appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

Is there a way to figure this tie breaker based on the points earned for each race, rather than on the Place (Rank)?  In other words, what if I don't know the Place the Racer finished, only the Points that they earned.  You would then order by "Most 25 points earned, then by most 24 points earned, then by most 23 points earned, etc"

Comment: How many racers? How many races? What the limit of your precision?

Comment: You know, asking a question and then dissappearing isn't considered very polite on this site...

Comment: @Henry - There could be 10s or 100s of racers.  Usually around 10-15 races, but could be as many as 20 or 25.  I would prefer to not be limited by numbers of racers or races.  Limit of precision?  Whatever I can do with the .NET programming language on a modern PC.

Comment: @5xum - Apologies.  I won't post a question right before bed time in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are $k-1$ races, then set the first place to be $25 + \frac1k$ points instead of $25$, and the second place $22+\frac1{k^2}$ and so on.

That way, the total number of points is equal to the total number as per the old scoring system plus

$$\text{number of wins}\cdot \frac{1}{k^1} + \text{number of second places}\frac1{k^2} + \cdots$$

And because there are only $k-1$ races, sorting by this number should make no errors.

**Note**: this doesn't even require you to have two columns, you just modify the points column so that ties do not happen.

Comment: Erm, better use $\frac{1}{k+1}$?

Comment: @user21820 I think it would also work with $k$, since you can only get an overflow if one person took the same place in all races. But I guess $k+1$ would be safer, yes.

Comment: @5xum - I know I specifically said the tie was broken based upon the "Rank" or "Place", but what if that was unknown and the only thing known was the "Points" earned for each race?  (See edited question).

Comment: @Scuzzlebutt Well can't you just sort all the different numbers of points that were earned and translate those back into positions?

Comment: @5xnum - Yes I could if I have to, and your original solution gets me "oh so close".  The edge case is that racers can also earn points in other ways (e.g. "working" an event, the club will give them some type of average or bonus points to compensate them for giving up their racing day in favor of helping the promoting club put the race on).  This means that they can be given arbitrary points, and those points don't correspond to a finish placement in the race, and may not even match up exactly with a placement (e.g. they could earn 23 points, which is in between 1st and 2nd place)

Comment: So I guess lack of response indicates that there isn't a good way to do it off of Points rather than Place.  This will solve the problem for most all cases.  I'll deal with the edge cases separately.  Thank you!

Comment: @Scuzzlebutt Yeah, sorry, I wanted to answer the question later, but then forgot about it. That was rude of me. I think that your system (unknown places, points, arbitrary extra points, dealing with ties) is quite complex, and therefore it's unlikely you can find a "magic wand" approach. The system is so complex you can expect the code that solves it to also have some complications.

Comment: @5xum - I didn't know if what I was asking was complicated or not.  Someone else (like you) has to tell me that!  I was thinking a possible solution could be to replace the exponent of k (which is currently the place) with (max points + 1 - points) which I think would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a limited number of races run and significant places, then you can encode a count of each place attained in a single number.

E.g., assuming only 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th places are significant and each racer runs 9 or fewer races, you could encode

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}&\text{Racer A}&\text{Racer B}&\text{Racer C}&\text{Racer D}\\\hline\text{# 1st places}&1&1&2&0\\\text{# 2nd places}&2&3&1&6\\\text{# 3rd places}&1&2&3&1\\\text{# 4th places}&3&1&1&0\\\hline\text{Encoding}&1213&1321&2131&0610\end{array}$

If the number of races run is more than 9 but less than 99, then you can encode the place counts as pairs of digits:

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}&\text{Racer A}&\text{Racer B}&\text{Racer C}&\text{Racer D}\\\hline\text{# 1st places}&16&31&22&50\\\text{# 2nd places}&72&43&12&61\\\text{# 3rd places}&11&23&13&41\\\text{# 4th places}&3&1&1&0\\\hline\text{Encoding}&16721103&31432301&22121301&50614100\end{array}$

If you need to take account of even more places, or 8 digits is too big for your native integer types, then you can use formatted strings of digits provided you zero pad them appropriately.

Comment: This solution is one I hadn't really thought of, and it could work.  However, wouldn't you have to sort the points for each rider before creating the encoding?  This is doable, but the ability to generate (or calculate) some sort of tie breaker field for each racer's finish individually (as in 5xum's answer) makes it extremely easy to calculate and store in the database in one swoop.